# acquire weather data from Observatory

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to embed the current data from HK observatory, it works in my computer but fails upon HTTP client.
there are some effect works well in local computer but disappears when putting on to public net, why ?
any good solutions ?
following is a piece of testing code … extracted from observatory's homepage
http://www.hko.gov.hk/contentc.htm

```
<div id="current_weather_area">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var CurrentWxData = new Array();
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.hko.gov.hk/wxinfo/json/rhrread_uc.xml",
        dataType: "json",
        //async: false,
        cache: false,
        success: function(currwxdata) {
            CurrentWxData[1] = currwxdata.RHRREAD.hkotemp; //Temp
            CurrentWxData[2] = currwxdata.RHRREAD.hkorh; //RH

            var Temp = CurrentWxData[1];
            var RH = CurrentWxData[2];
            var current_weather_htm = '';

            current_weather_htm += '溫度 : ' + Temp + 　'&deg;C' +
                '<br>濕度 : ' + RH + '%';

            $('#current_weather_area').html(current_weather_htm);
        }
    });
    </script>

</div>
```

I want it display on my front page … 
http://119.247.250.128/wasyoku/

Comment: If the site does not output CORS headers you will not be able to get with a direct ajax request, you will need a server side script to get it and then do an ajax request to that script

Comment: The said resource does not seems to allow cross origin requests not jsonp.... so the only solution I can think of is to use your server as a proxy.... ie you sent the ajax request to your server which internally will make a http request to the target resource and will return the data returned by the target resource to the browser...